# django list not destroyed between views

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am creating a list from some of the model data but I am not doing it correctly, it works but when I refresh the page in the broswer reportResults just gets added to. I hoped it would get garbage collected between requests but obviously I am doing something wrong, any ideas anyone??

Thanks,
Ewan

```
reportResults = []   #the list that doesn't get collected
def addReportResult(fix,description):  
    fix.description = description
    reportResults.append(fix)

def unitHistory(request,unitid, syear, smonth, sday, shour, fyear, fmonth, fday, fhour, type=None):
   waypoints = Fixes.objects.filter(name=(unitid))
    waypoints = waypoints.filter(gpstime__range=(awareStartTime, awareEndTime)).order_by('gpstime')[:1000]
    if waypoints:
        for index in range(len(waypoints)): 
...do stuff here selecting some waypoints and generating "description" text
                    addReportResult(waypointsindex,description) ##append the list with this, adding a text description

    return render_to_response('unitHistory.html', {'fixes': reportResults})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you're aware of the life cycle of requests, mod_wsgi will keep a process open to service multiple requests. That process gets recycled every so often but it is definitely not bound to a single request as you've assumed.

That means you need a local list. I would suggest moving the `addReportResult` function contents directly in-line, but that's not a great idea if it needs to be reusable or if the function is too long. Instead I'd make that function return the item, and you can collect the results locally.

```
def create_report(fix, description): # I've changed the name to snake_casing
    fix.description = description
    return fix

def unit_history(request,unitid, syear, smonth, sday, shour, fyear, fmonth, fday, fhour, type=None):
    reports = []
    waypoints = Fixes.objects.filter(name=(unitid))
    waypoints = waypoints.filter(gpstime__range=(awareStartTime, awareEndTime)).order_by('gpstime')[:1000]
    if waypoints:
        for index in range(len(waypoints)): 
            report = create_report(waypointsindex, description)
            reports.append(report)
    return render_to_response('unitHistory.html', {'fixes': reportResults})
```

Comment: I'm assuming mod_wsgi, but most webservers I'm aware of behave this way.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked well. And appreciate the explanation as well.  Out of interest I normally prefer camelCase, is there and advantage to using snake_case or personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same list each time, to fix it you need to restructure your code to create a new list on every request. This can be done in multiple ways and this is one such way:

```
def addReportResult(reportResults, fix,description):  
    fix.description = description
    reportResults.append(fix)

def unitHistory(request,unitid, syear, smonth, sday, shour, fyear, fmonth, fday, fhour, type=None):

    reportResults = [] # Here we create our local list that is recreated each request.

    waypoints = Fixes.objects.filter(name=(unitid))
    waypoints = waypoints.filter(gpstime__range=(awareStartTime, awareEndTime)).order_by('gpstime')[:1000]
    if waypoints:
        for index in range(len(waypoints)):
            # Do processing
            addReportResult(reportResults, waypointsindex, description)
            # We pass the list to the function so it can use it.

return render_to_response('unitHistory.html', {'fixes': reportResults})
```

If the `addReportResult` stays small you could also inline the `description` attribute set by removing the call to `addReportResult` altogether and doing the `waypointsindex.description = description` at the same position.

Comment: Hi Wessie, Unfortunately I have already tried that and I end with a totally empty list each time. The other answer to create list inside the function works. thank you very much for taking the time to help.